# What is the GenericType argument in a Typescript Promise<GenericType> definition?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

Just curious whether the generic type in Typescripts `Promise<GenericType>` promise definition the type of the object passed to the `then` handler?

For example this works:

```
    const pr:Promise<Array<Number>> = Promise.resolve([1, 2, 3]);

    const handler = (arg:Array<Number>)=> {
       console.dir(arg);
    }

    pr.then(handler);
```

Another related question.  If we make the `handler` a `handler:Function` then vscode complains / draws red squiggles under the `pr.then(handler`  part of the code.  Does typescript have a type that can be assigned to handler functions?

Comment: A promise is just a container for an asynchronous value like an array is a container for multiple values. You have to specify the type of the thing they contain.

Comment: Indeed - Just wanted to verify that the GenericType part is the return type that is the result of the asynchronous operation that the promise performs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just wanted to verify that the GenericType part is the return type that is the result of the asynchronous operation that the promise performs?

Not quite. There's no generic type in your example: you've given everything a concrete type.

What you want (I think) is this:

```
const pr:Promise<Array<Number>> = Promise.resolve([1, 2, 3]);

// handler here is declared with type Array<Number> -> void
const handler = (arg:Array<Number>): void => { // NOTE: void
   console.dir(arg);
}

pr.then(handler);
```

To illustrate the type preservation (and the necessity thereof):

```
// doubleToString has type Number -> String
const doubleToString = (n: Number): String => (n * 2).toString();
const doubledAndStringed: Promise<Array<String>> = pr.then(arr => arr.map(doubleToString));
```

Whereas the following fails:

```
const repeatString = (s: String): String => s.repeat(1);
const repeated: Promise<Array<String>> = pr.then(arr => arr.map(repeatString))
```

If you have a function that returns a Promise depending on the type of it's argument, you use a generic type:

```
const wrap = (x: T): Promise<T> => Promise.resolve(x);
```

Here `T` is the generic type, and typescript will preserve the *specific* type of the argument:

```
const wrappedString: Promise<String> = wrap('hello!');
```

Here `wrappedString` will have that concrete type whether you annotate it or not.